# PHP Class variable question

Tags: php

I have the following class which handles my user logged in / logged out (I only included what's relevant here). I want to redirect users who are logged in who visit login.php to there account page. I do this using....

```
    $User = new User();
if ($User->loggedin = 'true') header('Location:MyAccountNEW.php');
```

The issue is this redirects to myaccountnew.php weather I switch it to true or false.. (although it does not when the condition is (2>3). Aslo when I echo $User-loggedin, nothing comes up. I'm kinda stumped...

Heres the class

```
Class User {

public $loggedin = false;
public $username = "";
public $ShopperID = "";

function __construct() {
    $this->CheckLogin();
}

function CheckLogin() {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {
            $this->loggedin = true;
            $this->username = $_SESSION['Username'];
    }
    else {
        $this->loggedin = false;
    }
}
```

heres what logout.php looks like

```
<?php include ("base.php");
  include("userclass.php");

  $User = new User();
  $User->loggedin = false;
```

$_SESSION = array(); session_destroy(); ?>

Comment: Too quick for me :) 3 answers while typing my response.

Comment: Christ, I cannot believe I missed an extra equals sign lol. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a single equals (=) instead of two (==)

Also, I would *strongly* recommend adding this:

```
if ($User->loggedIn == 'true') {
    header('location: somewhereelse.php');
    die(); // <-- important!!
}
```

Also, since that property is a boolean, you should be comparing against the actual bool value `true` instead of the string `"true"`.

```
if ($User->loggedIn == true)

// or even shorter:

if ($User->loggedIn)
```

this is because:

```
true == "true"
true == "foo"
true == "false"
```

Any string value apart from an empty string or the string `"0"` is considered true.

Comment: excellent point about adding die() to prevent continued processing of the page

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if ($User->loggedin = 'true')
```

with

```
if ($User->loggedin == 'true')
```

because

```
if ($User->loggedin = 'true')
```

is an assignment and will always return true

probably just a typ0 of yours =]